# Display the icon at the right of the text in navigation view

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, rtl-language

sorry for my bad English.
I have a navigation drawer in some activities, I want the icon of each navigation view item to be placed to the right of that item's text and the whole item get right gravity.
Because I only used Persian in my app, I can not use "supportsRtl" in my code, if I use, it will look weird when I set device language to any rtl languages.

I think probably I can fix this with setting custom layout for navigation view, but I'm looking for a simpler way. this is my NavigationView XML code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:menu="@menu/menu"
    android:layout_gravity="end" />
```

[image]

[image]

**Edited :** 
layoutDirection is a good answer but  i used    
           `drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);`

for opening navigation drawer. now if device language be an rtl language this make app crash.

Comment: Try to add Custom Listview or RecylerView in Navigation drawer

Comment: thanks, it is a good way but in that case i will need a layout for item and an adapter class ,... . my code will become very longer only for solving this rtl problem . i'm looking for a simpler way or an custom library for it.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33464416/use-custom-layout-in-navigationdrawer-with-header-and-list/33464417#33464417

Comment: without `supportsRtl` not possible

Comment: thanks, but as i mentioned before. this way need very long code. But is there really no other way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Right to left menu items Android in NavigationView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45456410/right-to-left-menu-items-android-in-navigationview)

Comment: There is. See duplicate answer. Basically `android:layoutDirection="rtl"` and
`android:textDirection="rtl"`

Comment: ok , if i must use rtl , then can i disable system language effect in my app to prevent problem in rtl languages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make supportsRtl true and set the layout dirction to RTL on navigation View and LTR in other layouts

Comment: layout direction is a good answer but i used
drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
for opening navigation drawer. now if device language be an rtl language this make app crash. can i handle it with some solution?

Comment: thanks for your answer, i used gravityCompat.start but i must use Gravity.Right instead.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `android:layoutDirection="rtl"` to your `NavigationView`, like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     app:menu="@menu/menu"
     android:layoutDirection="rtl"
     android:layout_gravity="end" />
```